# Problem with Manipulate and FourierTrigSeries

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm facing a problem with Manipulate here, It just plots a blank xy-axis.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[FourierTrigSeries[-x^2 + a x, x, 10], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}], 
  {a, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: You need to add `Evaluate[]`: `Plot[Evaluate[FourierTrigSeries[(* stuff *)], (* stuff *)]`

Comment: i didn't understand, what does evaluate do in this case?

Answer (score 4):

J.M.'s advice, given in his comment, is one solution. Here is another using the plot option `Evaluated`. I also add custom x-axis ticks and give the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"` to the control variable `a` to make the manipulation more user friendly.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[FourierTrigSeries[-x^2 + a x, x, 10], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
    Ticks -> {Subdivide[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, 8], Automatic},
    Evaluated -> True],
  {a, -10, 10, .2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]